# Sprites in Object Pool spawning and updating, but not rendering

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been trying to draw sprites onto the world canvas. These sprites are held in a Group (aka object pool. They are meant to be bullets). They update properly, even go off bounds, but they never render!

The code below creates the engine, then after places a sprite onto the screen. This sprite will then 'shoot' out other sprites (That's where the issue is).

Engine:

```
var NE = (function() {
/* Public Variables */
var t = this;
this.images = {}; /* This is where all the loaded images are saved */
this.sprites = []; /* This is where are sprites are saved */
this.groups = []; /* This is where the groups are saved */
this.anim = ''; /* This is the main animation loop. Uses requestanimationframe to animate rooms */
this.canStart = false; /* Can the game start? Should be set to true when loading finishes */
this.rooms = {}; /* This is where all the rooms are saved. */
this.display = ''; /* Display canvas */
this.world = ''; /* This is the reference to the world canvas on which all the currrent running room's objects will live. */

var toBeLoaded = 0,
    /* Total number of images that need loading */
    isLoaded = 0,
    /* Images that have loaded */
    perLoadedDec = 0,
    /* Percentageloaded in decimal form */
    iDontDoAnything; /* Self explanatory, doesn't do anything */

this.Group = function(numEle, key, layer /*, obj*/ ) {
    /* Make sure theres an object value */
    /*if (obj === undefined) {
        obj = Sprite;
    }*/
    this.children = [];
    this.reloadTime = 0;
    this.isReload = false;
    /* Create array children with length numEle. The objects used will be obj */
    this.init = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < numEle; i++) {
            this.children[i] = t.sprites[t.sprites.push(t.addSprite(key, 100, 100, false)) - 1];
            // this.chilldren[i].groupName =
        }
    };

    /* Create a getFirstAlive() that checks for the first 'alive' element in the children[] and returns it */
    this.getFirstAlive = function() {
        var l = this.children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (this.children[i].alive) {
                console.log(this.children[i])
                return this.children[i];
            }
        }
    };

    this.getFirstDead = function() {
        var l = this.children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (!this.children[i].alive) {
                return this.children[i];
                break;
            }
            if (i >= l - 1) {
                console.log('There are no more sprites');
                if (!this.isReload) {
                    // this.setAllAliveAfter();
                    // this.isReload = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /* Create setAllAliveAfter(ms) which will set all children elements to alive after specified ms value. If none is given it happens immediately */
    this.setAllAliveAfter = function(ms) {
        var l = this.children.length;
        var ms = ms || this.reloadTime;
        console.log('Starting reloading')
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (this.children.alive) {
                break;
            } else {
                if (i >= l - 1) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                            this.children[i].alive = true;
                            if (i >= l - 1) {
                                console.log("done reseting")
                                this.isReload = false;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log('reloaded!')
                    }, ms); /* END SetTimeout */
                } /* END if */
            } /* END else */
        } /* END forLoop */
    };

    /* Set attribute for all objects in group */
    // debugger;
    this.setAttr = function(attr, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            this.children[i][attr] = value;
        }
    };

    t.groups.push(this);
    this.groupLength = (t.groups.length - 1 > 0) ? t.groups.length - 1 : 0;
    console.log(t.groups[this.groupLength]);
    return t.groups[this.groupLength];
}

this.Sprite = function(layer, key, x, y, isAlive) {
    /* Sprite Class */
    var spr = this;
    this.pos = t.Point(x, y);
    this.mass = 1;
    this.force = t.Vector();
    this.velocity = t.Vector();
    this.acceleration = t.Vector(this.force.x / this.mass, this.force.y / this.mass);
    // this.baseSpeed = t.Vector(170, 170);
    this.layer = layer || t.world; /* The layer onto which to draw this sprite */
    this.canvas = this.layer.canvas; /* The layer's canvas */
    this.ctx = this.layer.ctx; /* The layer canvas' drawing context */
    this.img = new Image(); /* The sprite's main image */
    this.img.src = t.images[key].src;
    this.group = undefined; /* This is the group to which this sprite controls */
    this.rotImg = undefined; /* The rotated version of the main image. To be used when rotating towards mouse/Vector */
    this.doIRotate = undefined;
    this.rotAngleRad = undefined; /* This is the angle between mouse and sprite */
    this.isClickable = false; /* Whether the sprite is clickable */
    this.acceptsClickEv = false; /* Whether the sprite accepts mouse click events or not*/
    this.mouse = t.Point();
    this.alive = isAlive || false; /* Whether the sprite should be drawn onto the world */
    this.checkOutOfBounds = false; /* Check if the out of bounds */
    this.killOutOfBounds = false; /* If out of bounds then kill the sprite */

    this.init = function() {
        /* Create the drawer canvas */
        // debugger
        this.drawer = undefined;
        this.cW = 0;
        this.cH = 0;
        this.imgW = this.img.width;
        this.imgH = this.img.height;
        // console.log('canvas width ' + this.cW + '. canvas height ' + this.cH + '. image width ' + this.imgW + '. image height ' + this.imgH + '.');
        /* Find dimensions for canvas */
        this.cW = (Math.sqrt(sqr(this.imgW / 2) + sqr(this.imgH / 2))) * 2;
        // console.log(this.cW + ' is hypotemus');
        this.cH = this.cW;
        this.imgOnDrawerX = 0 - (this.imgW / 2);
        this.imgOnDrawerY = 0 - (this.imgH / 2);
        // console.log('canvas width ' + this.cW + '. canvas height ' + this.cH)
        this.drawer = t.createCanvas(this.cW, this.cH, '0');
        this.drawer.ctx.translate(this.cW / 2, this.cH / 2);
        if (this.alive) {
            t.renderCanvas(this.drawer, this.img, this.imgOnDrawerX, this.imgOnDrawerY);
            t.renderWorld(this.drawer.canvas, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        }
        /* END Create the drawer canvas */

        /* Event Listeners */
        this.handleClick = function(m) {
            if (this.doIRotate) {
                this.setMouseToPointAngle(m);
                this.rotationInit(this.drawer);
            }
            this.customHandleClick(m);
        };
        this.handleSpriteClicked = function(m) {
            /* Handle collision between mouse and sprite */
        }
    };
    this.kill = function() {
        /* This will remove sprite from world canvas */
        if (this.alive) {
            this.alive = false;
            this.pos.x = 0;
            this.pos.y = 0;
            this.velocity = t.Vector(0, 0);
            this.acceleration = t.Vector(0, 0);
        }

    };
    this.outOfBounds = function() {
        if (this.checkOutOfBounds) {
            var x = this.pos.x,
                y = this.pos.y,
                cW = this.canvas.width,
                cH = this.canvas.height;
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > cW || y > cH) {
                if (this.killOutOfBounds) {
                    this.kill();
                    console.log('Yay killed!')
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    this.render = function(a) {
        /* This will place sprite onto x,y position and then draw it */
        if (!this.outOfBounds()) {
            this.alive ? renderWorld(this.drawer.canvas, this.pos.x, this.pos.y) : 'a';
            // console.log(this.alive)
        }
        // console.log('Rendering!!' + this.group)
    }
    this.update = function(dt) {
        /* This is the update function */

        this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x * dt;
        this.velocity.y += this.acceleration.y * dt;
        this.pos.x += this.velocity.x * dt;
        this.pos.y += this.velocity.y * dt;
        this.outOfBounds();

    };
    this.reset = function(x, y) {
        /* Bring a sprite back to life. Set alive to true */
        this.alive = true;
        this.pos.x = x;
        this.pos.y = y;
        console.log('Ive been reset!!')
    };

    if (this.alive) {
        this.init();
        this.render();
    } else {
        this.init();
    }
    t.sprites.push(this);
    return t.sprites[t.sprites.length - 1];
}
this.Sprite = Sprite;

function Room(obj) {
    this.create = obj.create;
    this.update = obj.update;
    return this;
}

this.mainGame = function(room) {
    var lastUpdate;
    room.create();
    var l = this.sprites.length;

    function loop() {
        stats.begin();
        var now = window.Date.now();

        if (lastUpdate) {
            var elapsed = (now - lastUpdate) / 1000;
            lastUpdate = now;

            // Update all game objects here.
            room.update();
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if (this.sprites[i].alive) {
                    this.sprites[i].update(elapsed);
                }
            }
            // ...and render them somehow.
            t.render();
        } else {
            // Skip first frame, so elapsed is not 0.
            lastUpdate = now;
        }
        stats.end();
        // This makes the `loop` function run 60 frames per second (or slower, depends on monitor's refresh rate).
        t.anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
};

this.renderCanvas = function(layer, img, x, y) {
    var canvas = layer.canvas,
        ctx = layer.canvas.getContext('2d');

    /* Draw image onto the canvas at position (x,y) */
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
};
this.renderWorld = function(img, x, y) {
    renderCanvas(this.world, img, x, y);
};
this.clearCanvas = function(layer) {
    var c = layer.canvas,
        cx = layer.ctx; /* Get the canvas and context of the layer onto which we draw onto */
    cx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); /* Clear the layer */
};
this.clearWorldCanvas = function() {
    clearCanvas(this.world);
};
this.render = function() {
    /* Render all the layers now */
    clearWorldCanvas();
    var l = this.sprites.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        this.sprites[i].render();
    }
};
this.addSprite = function( /*layer,*/ imgKey, x, y, isAlive) {
    return spr = new this.Sprite(this.world, imgKey, x, y, isAlive);
    // return spr;
};
this.addGroup = function(numEle, key, layer) {
    var grp = new this.Group(numEle, key, layer);
    grp.init();
    return grp;
};
/* ./Public Functions */

return this;
})();
```

main.js:

```
/* Thank YOU GOD for this code and may YOU Bless it
Col 3:23 "Whatever you do, work at it with all your heart, as working for the LORD, not for human masters" */

// All rights reserved by Kitanga Nday
var keyArray = [
    'box'
],
srcArray = [
    'img/box.png'
];

NE.init('displayCanvas', 700, 400, keyArray, srcArray);
NE.addRoom('room', {
    create: function() {
    var t = this;
    // debugger;
    this.spr = NE.addSprite('box', 10, 10, true);
    this.spr.doIRotate = true;
    this.spr.acceptsClickEv = true;
    this.bulletPool = NE.addGroup(40, 'box', NE.world);
    console.log(this.bulletPool);
    this.bulletPool.setAttr('checkOutOfBounds', true);
    this.bulletPool.setAttr('killOutOfBounds', true);
    this.bulletPool.setAttr('alive', false);
    this.bulletPool.reloadTime = 2000;
    this.spr.group = this.bulletPool;
    this.spr.customHandleClick = function(ev) {
        /* Take first alive element from bulletpool and reset on this sprite ==> spr. */
        var bullet = this.group.getFirstDead();
        // console.log(this.group);
        bullet.reset(this.pos.x + 20, this.pos.y + 20);
        bullet.applyImpulse(NE.Vector(10, 10));
        /* Give a speed relative to the normalized vector of mouse position. */

    }
},
update: function() {
    // this.spr.velocity = {x:0,y:0};
}
});
NE.startRoom('room');
```

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Blank</title>
<meta name="description" content="Game" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="displayCanvas"></div>
<script src="NDAY13ngine.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And you expect someone to read trough all that?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 All you need to do is look at the Group and Sprite Classes. Also check the main js if that's where the issue is. Otherwise I believe everything else should be fine. Ok maybe the render() might be off, but I can't tell.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 if you have any suggestions of what I should show, I'm all ears.

Comment: Show only the parts that are relevant. Currently there is just too much. Cut everything unnecessary out.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 so like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the sprite's `init` function.

Aparently, I started the drawing functions only if the sprite was alive. Since my sprite's image was drawn on a canvas, and fed to the main canvas, there was no image to draw.

To fix it, I had to set all children in the sprite to dead (aka `this.alive = false`).

```
if (this.alive) 
{
    t.renderCanvas(this.drawer, this.img, this.imgOnDrawerX, this.imgOnDrawerY);
    t.renderWorld(this.drawer.canvas, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
}
```